# Removing Error Indexes Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing

I have been working on a google app engine project for a little while.  I now have two Indexes that show status ERROR, and I think this is causing me to have other issues within my program.  How do you remove these indexes?  I have tried changing my datastore-indexes-auto.xml file but nothing has worked at removing these indexes.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Java has its own appcfg.sh.  (See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Deleting_Unused_Indexes)

Basically, you need to remove the bad indexes from your datastore-indexes.xml file and run the following command:

```
./appengine-java-sdk/bin/appcfg.sh vacuum_indexes myapp/war
```

Everything I saw until I found the above documentation said you had to do it via Python.  I kept looking because that seemed bad to have to use Python when you're developing in a Java environment.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

So the only way to remove index errors while using google app engine (java) is to download the python environment, download the python sdk for google app engine, make a project with the same name as your java projet and then use the appcfg.py utility and change the indexes in question.